# How to write HTML content in a panel when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, panel, dynamic-data

I want to load HTML content in a panel when a button is clicked. The content is generated from the c# code by fetching the database.

Currently I have to load the content on page load in the panel and make panel visible on button click. But that makes the website speed very low. So please tell how can I load html content on demand in panel?

The code to be written in the panel on button click should be this:

```
<p><%=databaseFuncs.getName() %></p>
```

So as you can see I want to things to happen on Button Click: First the C# code should be executed than it should be encapsulated in paragraph tag and then written to the panel. One by one for all database rows this should be repeated. Please help.

Also note than I don't want to use custom asp.net controls.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit rude, but did you ever read an asp.Net tutorial? To answer your question, simply add a `<asp:label>` and set up its text property from code behind. Or use a DataList or a repeater for databinding

Comment: I edited my question, I don't want to use server side controls. So please tell me the solution using html only

Comment: "I don't want to use server side controls"? Why? please clarify the question. You are working with asp.net, if the question is not related to asp.net (Client side update, web service call, etc.) you should rephrase it. I'm starting to guess you want to *dynamically* create html content on client side, based on some server method. Right?

Comment: ya you got it correct. But only in the panel when the button is clicked

Comment: In this case, I would decompose your problem in two separate questions, as this is, I believe, two questions. Please rewrite properly the question, to make it more clear. Try to imagine the reader, who has no knowledge of your context/requirements/etc., who have to understand quickly your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the

```
databaseFuncs
```

public and

```
databaseFuncs.getName()
```

public and your code should work...

If the code is inside runat="server" then just use '#' instead of '='